# Замена get url в Wordpress на ЧПУ

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, url

Есть у меня такая задача.
Сделал фильтр для вукомерс (простой по сути фильтр, через get запрос) все работает. Get запрос естественно есть в url. 
Надо его передлать на ЧПУ
Т.е. 
есть например такой url
www.site.com/?type=one
надо получить:
www.site.com/one

Может кто сталкивался?

За ранее спасибо! И легкого кода! )

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: да, это то что надо!

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить код на hook init:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^([^/]*)/', 'index.php?type=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```